# Including the Configurable product 'simple' products in catalog lists

Tags: configurable-product, catalog

I will be adding a configurable product that has two configurable attributes (e.g. size and color.)   For this product, I would like to show all the associated simple products in the catalog for one of the attributes (in my scenario, size).

However, when the user clicks through to the simple product page for that given size, I would like them to still be able to change the configuration for either size or color.

Is that possible through configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure simple products are set to visible for search and catalog than they will show in your category pages.

If you want simple products to link to there configurable product I would do the following.

Inside your product list template add some logic that checks if the product has a parent configurable, if so echo parent products url instead of the simple product url.

Comment: Thank you, so if I understand correctly, having the simple product load the configurable product requires some 'code' in the template?  I think I understand how echoing the parent configurable would work, but if this is in the template presumably I'd have to test a condition that this is a simple product with a configurable product parent first.

Does anyone have example code I might use?